# Flutter/Dart: Getting DataRows from Map<String, String> and show them as table in a widget

Tags: flutter, dictionary, dart, iterable

I want to show the contents of a Map<String, String> as table in my widget. How can I iterate the Map?
I am not sure if I could do this inside the Widget or if I have to do it "outside":

```
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  Test();
  static Map<String, String> myMap = {
    "col1 row1": "some value",
    "col1 row2": "another value",
    "col1 row3": "foo-value"
  };

  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Some title'),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Scrollbar(
            child: DataTable(
              columns: [
                DataColumn(
                  label: Text('Col 1'),
                ),
                DataColumn(
                  label: Text('Col 2'),
                ),
              ],
              rows: [
                // Want to show the map-data here, like
                // col1 row1 | some value
                // col1 row2 | another value
                // col1 row3 | foo-value
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Thanks a lot for help in advance!

Comment: Have your seen this [json_table](https://pub.dev/packages/json_table) package?

Comment: No, I haven't yet, but it seems to be very powerful. I will have a look at it, thanks for hint!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just map the entries of your `Map<String, String>` to your `DataRows` and `DataCells`:

```
rows: Test.myMap.entries
  .map(
    (entry) => DataRow(
      cells: [
        DataCell(Text(entry.key)),
        DataCell(Text(entry.value)),
      ],
    ),
  )
  .toList(),
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank a lot!

Comment: Just found this answer after hours of searching. Worked for me too! Thank you!!