# Display mapped data without a key value

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two `Lists` that are being combined into a single `Map`. One is a `String` (formattedDates) and the other is a `double` (unitsList). The map is working fine and prints properly, but now I need to display the mapped data in a `DataTable`, specifically in `DataCell`s and I am not sure how to call each pair from the `Map` in the two different `DataCell`s.

```
List<String> formattedDates = datesList.map((a) => DateFormat('Md').format(a)).toList();
List<double> unitsList = widget.logRecord.updatesUnits.toList();
final testMap = Map.fromIterables(formattedDates, unitsList);
print('testMap $testMap');

//output
//flutter: testMap {4/10: 200.0, 4/13: 400.0, 4/14: 600.0, 4/15: 800.0, 4/20: 1000.0, 4/23: 1500.0, 4/24: 2200.0, 4/25: 2500.0, 4/29: 4500.0, 5/1: 6500.0, 5/3: 8500.0, 5/6: 10500.0}
```

So the mapping is working. Now I need to display the pair in a `DataTable`

```
DataTable(
 columns: [
  DataColumn(label: Text('Date Updated')),
  DataColumn(label: Text('Unit added'))
  ],
 rows:  [DataRow(cells: [
  //this is where I do not know how to pull out the specific data in the testMap
  //this currently returns null values even though testMap is not null
  DataCell(Text('${testMap[formattedDates]}')),
  DataCell(Text('${testMap[unitsList]}'))
  ])
 ]
)
```

How can I pull those specific values out of the Map? And also have the table grow (more rows) are more things are added to the Map?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66216092/16806413) I was able to figure it out if anyone else runs into this problem.

```
DataTable(
  columns: [
    DataColumn(label: Text('Date Updated')),
    DataColumn(label: Text('Unit added'))
  ],
  rows:  testMap.entries.map((entry) =>
  DataRow(cells: [
    DataCell(Text('${entry.key}')),
    DataCell(Text('${entry.value}'))
  ])).toList()
)
```